# Install 2nd nvme with 2nd Linux; will grub install properly?

Tags: linux, boot, debian, grub

I have a Dell laptop with Debian 12 on an internal 2TB nvme device and grub. I wish to install a 4TB device in the 2nd nvme slot, and install Debian 12 on that 2nd nvme as well, which will be configured differently for investigative purposes.

When I install on the 2nd nvme, will the grub installation be such that I'll be able to choose which nvme to boot from?